# How to use System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod with CoreCLR and CoreFX?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, coreclr

I need `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` for pre jitting.

but I can't find reference DLL for it in CoreFX and CoreCLR.

How can I build it? what package has this class and method??

Comment: Use the source, Luke. [The most recent version](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ffeef85a626d7344fd3e2031f749c356db0628d3/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs) includes this method, but its implementation is a no-op under CoreCLR. You can stub out the calling code with a conditional define or get the latest Core bits (but the call will still not do anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod()` did not exist in .Net Core 1.x, so you won't be able to use it there.

The method was added in .Net Core 2.0, but [it doesn't do anything there](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/v2.0.7/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs#L90).

In the upcoming .Net Core 2.1, [it will actually compile the given method](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ad0f22c/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs#L89-L98). (And [only the given method](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/16382#issue-169051458).)

Comment: Do you know of any alternative way to force the JITting of a method on .NET Core?